# 'IDataProtectionBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault' MVC dotnet core 3.1

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I am getting an error that ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault can't be added to IDataProtectionBuilder in an MVC Startup.cs dotnet 3.1 class

Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault is referenced and the PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage is working fine, but I would like to use an Azure Key Vault to encrypt the keys at rest.

According to the [Microsoft documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest?view=aspnetcore-3.1) this code should work

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri("<blobUriWithSasToken>"))
        .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault("<keyIdentifier>", "<clientId>", "<clientSecret>");
}
```

Here's my code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(Configuration["AzureDataProtection:StorageConnectionString"], out CloudStorageAccount storageAccount))
        {
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(Configuration["AzureDataProtection:ContainerName"]);
            container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(container, $"{Configuration["AzureDataProtection:ApplicationName"]}{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}keys.xml")
            .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(Configuration["AzureDataProtection:DataProtectionKey"], Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID"), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"));
            .SetApplicationName(Configuration["AzureDataProtection:ApplicationName"]);
        }
}
```

I've been working on the assumption I have missed a package but can't work out what- here's the entire project file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <UserSecretsId>ed790662-005d-4160-802c-4900c2d6daf0</UserSecretsId>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>True</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Styles\ovbootstrap.css" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Auth" Version="1.43.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Drive.v3" Version="1.43.0.1835" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Sheets.v4" Version="1.43.0.1848" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.10.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Temp\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Shared\Components\MeasurerSurveyorFitterFilterMenu\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Shared\Components\ExportHeaderSummary\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\css\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\js\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\lib\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\images\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But I get this error: CS1061 'IDataProtectionBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault' and no accessible extension method 'ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault' accepting a first argument of type 'IDataProtectionBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've tried referencing Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage as well as through cleaning / rebuilding.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's a semicolon before the `.SetApplicationName` – are you sure that this is exactly your code? There is a using for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection`? And `PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage` works but `ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault` doesn't?

Comment: Well apart form the semicolon, yes!  I have the ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault commented out so it compiles and moved the semicolon up.  And yes, PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage works but ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault doesn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are lacking the Key Vault package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureKeyVault/.

I found this out by googling the name, which lead me to the assembly name where this function is defined.

Comment: Thank you!  And for my future use, thanks for explaining how you worked it out!

Comment: In my case I needed to install the AzureKeyVault package as well as Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage just in case anybody else gets stuck